# how to extract specific character using str_extrac() in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

**Context**

I have a character vector `a`.

I want to extract the text between the last slash(`/`) and the `.nc` using the `str_extract()`function.

I have tried like this: `str_extract(a, "(?=/).*(?=.nc)")`, but failed.

**Question**

How can I get the text between the last lash and `.nc` in  character vector `a`.

**Reproducible code**

```
a = c(
  'data/temp/air/pm2.5/pm2.5_year_2014.nc',
  'data/temp/air/pm10/pm10_year_2014.nc',
  'efcv/asdfe/weewr/rtrkhh/ss_fef_10233_dfdfe.nc'
)

# My solution (failed)

str_extract(a, "(?=/).*(?=.nc)")
# [1] "/temp/air/pm2.5/pm2.5_year_2014"       
# [2] "/temp/air/pm10/pm10_year_2014"         
# [3] "/asdfe/weewr/rtrkhh/ss_fef_10233_dfdfe"


# The expected output should like this:

# [1] "pm2.5_year_2014"       
# [2] "pm10_year_2014"         
# [3] "ss_fef_10233_dfdfe"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex replacement approach:

```r
a = c(
    'data/temp/air/pm2.5/pm2.5_year_2014.nc',
    'data/temp/air/pm10/pm10_year_2014.nc',
    'efcv/asdfe/weewr/rtrkhh/ss_fef_10233_dfdfe.nc'
)
output <- gsub(".*/|\\.[^.]+$", "", a)
output

[1] "pm2.5_year_2014"    "pm10_year_2014"     "ss_fef_10233_dfdfe"
```

Here is the regex logic:

- `.*/` match everything from the start of the string until the last /
- `|` OR
- `\.[^.]+$` match everything from final dot until the end of the string

Then we replace these matches by empty string to remove them, leaving behind the filenames.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. One thing I don't understand is what is the scope of `$`. In your code, `$` affects `\\.[^.]+`. why wouldn't it only affect `[^.]+` or on the whole regular expression `.*/|\\.[^.]+`.

Comment: Well `A|B` evaluates to true if _either_ the complete `A` expression or the complete `B` expression be true.  So the `$` can be thought to "belong" only to the expression on the right.